Import aliases seems to be broken with Playwright
For some reason, I can't get my Vite aliases to work with Playwright. The module resolution seems to work in the IDE (file path is correctly displayed on hover/no error). However, when I import a file with a @/ import or a relative file that has an @/ import inside, the test file disappears within Playwright. This can be pretty frustrating because we can't reuse helpers methods created for the app inside tests. It seems to break especially when importing barrel files (e.g. @/utils for src/utils/index.ts).
I'm using @playwright/test@1.47.0 and here is my configuration.
tsconfig.json
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    }
  ]
}

tsconfig.node.json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.node.json",
  "include": ["vite.config.*", "package.json", "scripts/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node", "vitest/globals"],
    "preserveValueImports": false,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",
    "lib": ["ESNext"]
  }
}

tsconfig.app.json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": ["*.ts", "*.d.ts", "src/**/*", "docs/**/*.vue", "**/*.story.vue", "**/*.vue", "**/*.json", "src/tests", "src/tests/e2e"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "lib": ["es2021", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@selectors": ["src/tests/shared/selectors"],
      "@selectors/*": ["src/tests/shared/selectors/*"],
      "@routes": ["src/utils/tests/e2e/routes"]
    },
    "types": ["@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/messages", "vuetify", "node", "vitest/globals"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "preserveValueImports": false,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true
  }
}

vite.config.ts
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import * as path from 'node:path'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite'
import { visualizer } from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'
import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader'
import { configDefaults } from 'vitest/config'

import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

import pkg from './package.json'

import type { PluginOption } from 'vite'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const plugins: PluginOption[] = [
    vue(),
    vuetify({
      autoImport: {
        ignore: ['Tooltip'],
      },
    }),
    // https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-svg-loader
    svgLoader({
      defaultImport: 'component',
    }),

    AutoImport({
      imports: [
        'vue',
        {
          from: 'vue',
          imports: ['CSSProperties', 'VNodeRef', 'Directive', 'UnwrapRef', 'WatchStopHandle', 'MaybeRef', 'StyleValue'],
          type: true,
        },
        '@vueuse/core',
        'vue-i18n',
        {
          from: 'vue-i18n',
          imports: ['Composer'],
          type: true,
        },
        'vue-router',
        {
          from: 'vue-router',
          imports: [
            'BreadcrumbToParam',
            'RouteBreadcrumbItem',
            'RouteBreadcrumbMeta',
            'RouteLocationNamedRaw',
            'RouteLocationNormalized',
            'RouteLocationRaw',
            'RouteParams',
            'RouteRecordRaw',
          ],
          type: true,
        },
      ],
      dts: './src/types/declarations/auto-imports.d.ts',
    }),

    VueI18nPlugin({
      include: path.resolve(path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), './src/locales/**'),
    }),
    Components({
      globs: ['src/components/Functional/*/App*.vue', 'src/components/UI/*/App*.vue'],
      dts: 'src/types/declarations/components.d.ts',
    }),

    nodePolyfills({
      include: ['path', 'url', 'fs', 'stream', 'util'],
      // Override the default polyfills for specific modules
      overrides: {
        // Since `fs` is not supported in browsers, we can use the `memfs` package to polyfill it
        fs: 'memfs',
      },
    }),
  ]

  if (mode === 'bundle-analyze') {
    plugins.push(visualizer() as PluginOption)
  }

  const bundledFileVersion = `${pkg.version}-${Date.now()}`
  const generateSourcemaps = !!process.env.VITE_GENERATE_SOURCEMAPS

  return {
    build: {
      sourcemap: generateSourcemaps ? 'inline' : false,
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          assetFileNames: `assets/[name]-${bundledFileVersion}[extname]`,
          chunkFileNames: `assets/[name]-${bundledFileVersion}.js`,
          entryFileNames: `assets/[name]-${bundledFileVersion}.js`,
        },
      },
    },
    optimizeDeps: { exclude: ['fsevents', 'maska', 'vuetify', '@vuepic/vue-datepicker', 'vue-echarts', 'echarts'] },
    plugins,
    server: {
      port: 3000,
      strictPort: true,
    },
    preview: {
      port: 3000,
      strictPort: true,
    },
    define: {
      __APP_ENV__: {
        VERSION: mode === 'production' ? pkg.version : `${pkg.version}-${mode.toLocaleUpperCase()}`,
      },
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
        '@selectors': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/tests/shared/selectors', import.meta.url)),
        // To make AWS happy
        './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser',
        'source-map-js': 'source-map',
      },
    },
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          additionalData: `
            @use '@/styles/variables' as wfv;
            @use '@/styles/mixins' as mixins;
            
            @import '@/styles/functions.scss';
          `,
        },
      },
      postcss: {
        plugins: [
          {
            postcssPlugin: 'internal:charset-removal',
            AtRule: {
              charset: (atRule) => {
                if (atRule.name === 'charset') {
                  atRule.remove()
                }
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    test: {
      globals: true,
      environment: 'jsdom',
      globalSetup: 'src/tests/integration/global-setup.ts',
      setupFiles: ['src/tests/integration/setup.ts'],
      exclude: [...configDefaults.exclude, 'src/tests/e2e', 'src/modules/**/e2e'],
      server: {
        deps: {
          external: [
            '**/node_modules/**',
            '**/dist/**',
            '**/dist-docs/**',
            '**/coverage/**',
            '**/svg/**',
            '**/mocks/**',
            'vuetify/lib/directives/tooltip/index.mjs',
          ],
          inline: ['vuetify'],
        },
      },
      coverage: {
        all: true,
        provider: 'istanbul',
        include: ['src/**/*.ts', 'src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.vue'],
        exclude: ['src/tests', 'node_modules'],
        reporter: ['text', 'json-summary'],
      },
    },
  }
})



Playwright obviously ignores vite config. Try to add baseUrl and paths to main tsconfig,  https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/7121#issuecomment-1009140849 . It could be a problem with "references"

I've seen this discussion and tried it already but it doesn't seem to solve the issue unfortunately, the test still disappears from Playwright as soon as I import a @/ file

Can you provide a reproduction? Currently this looks like a bug or regression, but you'd need a repro to report it any way
